# Setting meta server control content to method return value

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am working on a user control in which I want to meta data to the head I am building against .NET 3.5.I want some of the meta tags content to be dynamic, the result of a method call. Here is an example of what I am doing in my user control:

```
<meta id = "metaOgUrl" property="og:url" content="<%=this.GetOgImage()%>" runat = "server"/>
```

and the GetOgImage() in the code behind:

```
public string GetOgImage()
{
    if (entry != null)
    {
        return entry.PhotoUrl; 
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

nice and simple right? The issue is that I am seeing the method call itself rendered in the browser as the content value:

```
<meta id="tmpl_appmain_block1_ctl00_metaOgUrl" content="<%=this.GetOgImage()%>" property="og:url">
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? According to what I have read this should be working. Any help would be appreciated, thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes code in the head tag gets dorked up, but you can remove the runat=server attribute and do this as a hack:

```
<meta id="metaOgUrl" property="og:url" content="<%= "" + GetOgImage() %>" />
```

Alternatively, leave the runat=server and remove the content attribute and set it in the code-behind

```
<meta id="metaOgUrl" runat="server" property="og:url" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    metaOgUrl.Attributes["content"] = GetOgImage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I opted for the second option.